# after use fetchcolumn() while loop is not working correctly in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new in PHP and I am using PDO right now for making my website more secure but when I use fetchcolumn() then the while loop is not working correctly.
it does not return all row.

here is my code

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM impdate where joblink=? and status='y' order by id desc");
 if ($stmt->execute(array($joblink))) {
   $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
   if ($rows == "") {
     echo '<style type="text/css">.impdate{display: none;}</style>';
   }else{
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
          echo'<tr><td>'.$row['title'].'</td> <td>'.$row['date'].'</td></tr>';
       }
    }
 }
```

help me, please.....

**Note** : When I remove fetchcolumnl and run only while loop then it work correctly

Comment: use $rows = $stmt->rowCount(); instead of  $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

Comment: thanks bro its working for me thank you so much

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green ticks its useful to future user @Smart Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
use $rows = $stmt->rowCount(); instead of $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

$rows = $stmt->fetchColumn(); is used to get the single row only .